# Najas on clothes

Tags: wudu, fard

As Salam alaikum. I have prostatitis. And when I wash myself, sometimes there is a feeling that urine comes out, I check and there are drops of liquid on the tip itself, but at the same time it can be urine and at the same time it can be water. What to do in such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when something was initially pure but there is doubt about it becoming Najis, it should still be considered pure. And it should be considered najis only if you are sure it is najis.

Also, it is recommended for men to perform the action of Istibra.

> Istibra Issue 73: Istibra is a recommended act for men after
> urinating. Its object is to ensure that no more urine is left in the
> urethra.
>
> There are certain ways of performing Istibra, and the best of them is
> that after the passing of urine, if the anus also becomes najis it is
> made Clean (tahir/pak) first. Thereafter, the part between the anus
> and the root of penis should be pressed thrice, with the mid dle
> finger of the left hand. Then the thumb is placed on the penis, and
> the forefinger below it pressing three times up to the point of
> circumcision, then the front part of the penis should be jerked three
> times.
>
> Issue 74: The moisture which is discharged by man during wooing and
> courtship, is called 'Mazi'. It is Clean (tahir/pak), and so is the
> liquid which is seen after ejaculation. It is called 'Wazi'.
> Similarly, the liquid which at times comes out after urine, is called
> 'Wadi' and it is Clean (tahir/pak) if urine has not reached it. If a
> person performs Istibra after urinating, and then discharges liquid
> doubting whether it is urine, or one of the above mentioned three
> liquids, that liquid is Clean (tahir/pak).
>
> Issue 75: If a person doubts whether he has performed Istibra or not,
> and then discharges a liquid about which he is not sure whether it is
> Clean (tahir/pak) or not, that liquid is will be deemed najis, and if
> he has performed Wudhu it becomes void. However, if he doubts whe ther
> he performed the Istibra correctly or not, and a liquid is discharged
> about which he is not sure whether it is Clean (tahir/pak) or not,
> that liquid will be Clean (tahir/pak), and it will not invalidate the
> Wudhu.
>
> Issue 76: * If a person performs Istibra, and also performs Wudhu, and
> if after Wudhu he sees a liquid discharged, of which he knows that it
> is either urine or semen, it will be obligatory upon him to do Ghusl,
> together with Wudhu. But if he had not done Wudh u after Istibra, then
> Wudhu alone will be sufficient.
>
> Issue 77: When enough time has lapsed since urinating, and one becomes
> sure that no urine is left in urinary passage, and then he sees some
> liquid, doubting whether it is Clean (tahir/pak) or not, he will
> consider it as Clean (tahir/pak), even if he had not done Istibra. If
> he has Wudhu, it will be valid.
>
> Issue 78: Istibra is not meant for women, and if she sees any liquid
> and she doubts whether it is urine, that liquid is Clean (tahir/pak),
> and it will not invalidate Wudhu and Ghusl.

[Reference](https://www.al-islam.org/islamic-laws-sayyid-ali-hussaini-sistani/taharat)